# What does async/await do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

I'm trying to wrap my head around async/await in python.

Am I on the right track?

- `async` and `@coroutine` functions returns coroutine/generator, not the returned value.
- `await` extracts the actual return value of coroutine/generator.
- `async` function result (coroutines) is meant to be added to event-loop.
- `await` creates "bridge" between event-loop and awaited coroutine (enabling the next point).
- `@coroutine`'s `yield` communicates directly with event-loop. (skipping direct caller which awaits the result)
- `await` can be used only inside async functions.
- `yield` can be used only inside `@coroutine`.

(`@coroutine` = `@types.coroutine`)

Answer (score 16):

> `async` and `@coroutine` functions returns coroutine/generator, not the returned value

To be technical, `types.coroutine` returns a generator-based coroutine which is different than generators and different than coroutines.

> await extracts the actual return value of coroutine/generator.

[`await`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression), similar to `yield from`, suspends the execution of the coroutine until the awaitable it takes completes and returns the result.

> async function result (coroutines) is meant to be added to event-loop.

Yes.

> await creates "bridge" between event-loop and awaited coroutine (enabling the next point).

await creates a suspension point that indicates to the event loop that some I/O operation will take place thereby allowing it to switch to another task.

> @coroutine's yield communicates directly with event-loop. (skipping direct caller which awaits the result)

No, generator-based coroutines use `yield from` in a similar fashion to `await`, not `yield`.

> await can be used only inside async functions.

Yes.

> yield can be used only inside coroutine.

`yield from` can be used inside generator-based coroutines (generators decorated with `types.coroutine`) and, since Python 3.6, in `async` functions that result in an asynchronous generator.

Comment: I investigated further. In answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46462604/3595112, when `inner_coro` does `yield`, control flow goes to event loop, skipping initial caller `outer_async`. Given this example, would you agree that here `yield` is a way for coroutine to communicate directly with event loop?

Answer (score 0):

Demo code:

(illustrates whole control flow between `async` and `types.coroutine` and event loop)

```
import types


class EL:
    """Fake An event loop."""

    def __init__(self, outer_async):
        self.outer_async = outer_async

    def loop(self):
        print('    EL.loop : outer_async.send(None)')
        send_result = self.outer_async.send(None) # seed outer_async.
        print('    EL.loop : outer_async.send(None) -> outer_async_send_result = {}'.format(send_result))

        do_loop = True
        loop_counter = 0

        while do_loop:
            print()
            loop_counter += 1
            try:
                arg = send_result + '-loop(send-{})'.format(loop_counter)
                print('    EL.loop.while : task.outer_async.send({})'.format(arg))
                send_result = self.outer_async.send(arg) # raises StopIteration.
                print('    EL.loop.while : task.outer_async.send({}) -> send_result = {}'.format(arg, send_result))
            except StopIteration as e:
                print('    EL.loop.while : except StopIteration -> {}'.format(e.value))
                do_loop = False
        return loop_counter


async def outer_async(label):
    inner_coro_arg = label + '-A1'
    print('        outer_async({}) : await inner_coro({})'.format(label, inner_coro_arg))
    await_result = await inner_coro(inner_coro_arg)
    print('        outer_async({}) : await inner_coro({}) -> await_result = {}'.format(label, inner_coro_arg, await_result))

    inner_coro_arg = label + '-A2'
    print('        outer_async({}) : await inner_coro({})'.format(label, inner_coro_arg))
    await_result = await inner_coro(inner_coro_arg)
    print('        outer_async({}) : await inner_coro({}) -> await_result = {}'.format(label, inner_coro_arg, await_result))
    return 555555


@types.coroutine
def inner_coro(inner_coro_label):
    yld_arg = inner_coro_label + '-C(yield)'
    print('            inner_coro({}) : yield({})'.format(inner_coro_label, yld_arg))
    yield_result = yield yld_arg
    print('            inner_coro({}) : yield({}) -> yield_result = {}'.format(inner_coro_label, yld_arg, yield_result))
    return_value = yield_result + '-C(return)'
    print('            inner_coro({}) : return -> {}'.format(inner_coro_label, return_value))
    return return_value


def main():
    loop = EL(outer_async('$$'))
    print('main() : loop.loop')
    loop_outer_async = loop.loop()
    print('main() : loop.loop -> {}'.format(loop_outer_async))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
main() : loop.loop
    EL.loop : outer_async.send(None)
        outer_async($$) : await inner_coro($$-A1)
            inner_coro($$-A1) : yield($$-A1-C(yield))
    EL.loop : outer_async.send(None) -> outer_async_send_result = $$-A1-C(yield)

    EL.loop.while : task.outer_async.send($$-A1-C(yield)-loop(send-1))
            inner_coro($$-A1) : yield($$-A1-C(yield)) -> yield_result = $$-A1-C(yield)-loop(send-1)
            inner_coro($$-A1) : return -> $$-A1-C(yield)-loop(send-1)-C(return)
        outer_async($$) : await inner_coro($$-A1) -> await_result = $$-A1-C(yield)-loop(send-1)-C(return)
        outer_async($$) : await inner_coro($$-A2)
            inner_coro($$-A2) : yield($$-A2-C(yield))
    EL.loop.while : task.outer_async.send($$-A1-C(yield)-loop(send-1)) -> send_result = $$-A2-C(yield)

    EL.loop.while : task.outer_async.send($$-A2-C(yield)-loop(send-2))
            inner_coro($$-A2) : yield($$-A2-C(yield)) -> yield_result = $$-A2-C(yield)-loop(send-2)
            inner_coro($$-A2) : return -> $$-A2-C(yield)-loop(send-2)-C(return)
        outer_async($$) : await inner_coro($$-A2) -> await_result = $$-A2-C(yield)-loop(send-2)-C(return)
    EL.loop.while : except StopIteration -> 555555
main() : loop.loop -> 2
```

Comment: This istoo complex.

Comment: what this code demonstrate it that: yield will generate the result and **hang** the coroutine to the `send` method, however,  await not, notice that there two continue await function run. ```