# Does `await` in Python yield to the event loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I was wondering what exactly happens when we `await` a coroutine in async Python code, for example:

```
await send_message(string)
```

(1) `send_message` is added to the event loop, and the calling coroutine gives up control to the event loop, or

(2) We jump directly into `send_message`

Most [explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46364261/2111778) I read point to (1), as they describe the calling coroutine as *exiting*. But my own experiments suggest (2) is the case: I tried to have a coroutine run after the caller but before the callee and could not achieve this.

Comment: We do jump into `send_message` but there needs to be something asynchronous such as `asyncio.sleep(...)`, or this is just meaningless... In short, `await` allows the context to switch. Or you can think that the rest code is a callback function of this `send_message(string)`.

Comment: @Sraw  So every `await` statement is just adding to a call stack, except for `await asyncio.sleep(...)` which jumps up the whole call stack and back into the event loop?

Comment: No, ah, hard to explain. I suppose you first fully understand how asynchronous IO works. Eventually, it is based on callback. `async/await` is just syntax sugar for it, all the code below `await` can be treated as the callback function of this asynchronous action. So you do first execute this function, but the context will switch when hit an asynchronous action. Or if you don't have any synchronous action in your awaited function, then there is almost no difference with a synchronous one.

Comment: @Sraw The thing that confuses me is that we have an `async def` awaiting another `async def` which awaits another `async def` -- "turtles all the way down" so to say. When and how do we back up to the event loop, if not with `await asncio.sleep(...)`?

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep(...)` is just an example. The example you give is the same as a callback hell in the old days. Now we have a syntax sugar to save us from this hell. But the underlying is the same, just think in that way, it will be clear.

Comment: For an explanation of the mechanism behind Python's `await`, take alook at [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JtNiwCH_OA). Disclaimer: I am the lecturer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No, `await` (per se) does *not* yield to the event loop, `yield` yields to the event loop, hence for the case given: "(2) We jump directly into `send_message`". In particular, certain `yield` expressions are the *only* points, at bottom, where async tasks can actually be switched out (in terms of nailing down the precise spot where Python code execution can be suspended).

To be proven and demonstrated: 1) by theory/documentation, 2) by implementation code, 3) by example.

## By theory/documentation

[PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression): **Coroutines with `async` and `await` syntax**

> While the PEP is not tied to any specific Event Loop implementation, it is relevant only to the kind of coroutine that uses `yield` as a signal to the scheduler, indicating that the coroutine will be waiting until an event (such as IO) is completed. ...
>
> [`await`] uses the `yield from` implementation [with an extra step of validating its argument.] ...
>
> Any `yield from` chain of calls ends with a `yield`. This is a fundamental mechanism of how `Future`s are implemented. Since, internally, coroutines are a special kind of generators, every `await` is suspended by a `yield` somewhere down the chain of await calls (please refer to PEP 3156 for a detailed explanation). ...
>
> Coroutines are based on generators internally, thus they share the implementation. Similarly to generator objects, coroutines have `throw()`, `send()` and `close()` methods. ...
>
> The vision behind existing generator-based coroutines and this proposal is to make it easy for users to see where the code might be suspended.

In context, "easy for users to see where the code might be suspended" seems to refer to the fact that in synchronous code `yield` is the place where execution can be "suspended" within a routine allowing other code to run, and that principle now extends perfectly to the async context wherein a `yield` (if its value is not consumed *within* the running task but is propagated up to the scheduler) is the "signal to the scheduler" to switch out tasks.

More succinctly: where does a generator yield control? At a `yield`. Coroutines (including those using `async` and `await` syntax) are generators, hence likewise.

And it is not merely an analogy, in implementation (see below) *the actual mechanism* by which a task gets "into" and "out of" coroutines is not anything new, magical, or unique to the async world, but simply by calling the coro's [`<generator>.send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) method. That was (as I understand the text) part of the "vision" behind PEP 492: `async` and `await` would provide no novel mechanism for code suspension but just pour async-sugar on Python's already well-beloved and powerful generators.

And
[PEP 3156](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/#debug-mode): *The "asyncio" module*

> The `loop.slow_callback_duration attribute` controls the maximum execution time allowed between two *yield points* before a slow callback is reported [emphasis in original].

That is, an uninterrupted segment of code (from the async perspective) is demarcated as that between two successive `yield` points (whose values reached up to the running `Task` level (via an `await`/`yield from` tunnel) without being consumed within it).

And this:

> The scheduler has no public interface. You interact with it by using `yield from future` and `yield from task`.

Objection: "That says '`yield from`', but you're trying to argue that the task can *only* switch out at a `yield` itself! `yield from` and `yield` are different things, my friend, and `yield from` itself doesn't suspend code!"

Ans: Not a contradiction. The PEP is saying *you* interact with the scheduler by using `yield from future/task`. But as noted above in PEP 492, any chain of `yield from` (~aka `await`) ultimately reaches a `yield` (the "bottom turtle"). In particular (see below), `yield from future` does in fact `yield` that same `future` after some wrapper work, and that `yield` is the actual "switch out point" where another task takes over. But it is incorrect for *your code* to directly `yield` a `Future` up to the current `Task` because you would bypass the necessary wrapper.

The objection having been answered, and its practical coding considerations being noted, the point I wish to make from the above quote remains: that a suitable `yield` in Python async code is ultimately *the one thing* which, having suspended code execution in the standard way that any other `yield` would do, *now futher* engages the scheduler to bring about a possible task switch.

## By implementation code

[asyncio/futures.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/futures.py)

```
class Future:
...
    def __await__(self):
        if not self.done():
            self._asyncio_future_blocking = True
            yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
        if not self.done():
            raise RuntimeError("await wasn't used with future")
        return self.result()  # May raise too.

    __iter__ = __await__  # make compatible with 'yield from'.
```

Paraphrase: The line `yield self` is what tells the running task to sit out for now and let other tasks run, coming back to this one sometime after `self` is done.

Almost all of your awaitables in `asyncio` world are (multiple layers of) wrappers around a `Future`. The event loop remains utterly blind to all higher level `await awaitable` expressions until the code execution trickles down to an `await future` or `yield from future` and then (as seen here) calls `yield self`, which yielded `self` is then "caught" by none other than the `Task` under which the present coroutine stack is running thereby signaling to the task to take a break.

Possibly the one and only exception to the above "code suspends at `yield self` within `await future`" rule, in an `asyncio` context, is the potential use of a *bare* `yield` such as in `asyncio.sleep(0)`. And since the `sleep` function is a topic of discourse in the comments of this post, let's look at that.

[asyncio/tasks.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py)

```
@types.coroutine
def __sleep0():
    """Skip one event loop run cycle.
    This is a private helper for 'asyncio.sleep()', used
    when the 'delay' is set to 0.  It uses a bare 'yield'
    expression (which Task.__step knows how to handle)
    instead of creating a Future object.
    """
    yield


async def sleep(delay, result=None, *, loop=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay <= 0:
        await __sleep0()
        return result

    if loop is None:
        loop = events.get_running_loop()
    else:
        warnings.warn("The loop argument is deprecated since Python 3.8, "
                      "and scheduled for removal in Python 3.10.",
                      DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)

    future = loop.create_future()
    h = loop.call_later(delay,
                        futures._set_result_unless_cancelled,
                        future, result)
    try:
        return await future

    finally:
        h.cancel()
```

Note: We have here the two interesting cases at which control can shift to the scheduler:

(1) The bare `yield` in `__sleep0` (when called via an `await`).

(2) The `yield self` immediately within `await future`.

The crucial line (for our purposes) in [asyncio/tasks.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py) is when `Task._step` runs its top-level coroutine via `result = self._coro.send(None)` and recognizes fourish cases:

(1) `result = None` is generated by the coro (which, again, *is* a generator): the task "relinquishes control for one event loop iteration".

(2) `result = future` is generated within the coro, with further magic member field evidence that the future was yielded in a proper manner from out of `Future.__iter__ == Future.__await__`: the task relinquishes control to the event loop until the future is complete.

(3) A `StopIteration` is raised by the coro indicating the coroutine completed (i.e. as a generator it exhausted all its `yield`s): the final result of the task (which is itself a `Future`) is set to the coroutine return value.

(4) Any other `Exception` occurs: the task's `set_exception` is set accordingly.

Modulo details, the main point for our concern is that coroutine segments in an `asyncio` event loop ultimately run via `coro.send()`. Initial startup and final termination aside, `send()` proceeds precisely from the last `yield` value it generated to the next one.

## By example

```
import asyncio
import types

def task_print(s):
    print(f"{asyncio.current_task().get_name()}: {s}")

async def other_task(s):
    task_print(s)

class AwaitableCls:
    def __await__(self):
        task_print("    'Jumped straight into' another `await`; the act of `await awaitable` *itself* doesn't 'pause' anything")
        yield
        task_print("    We're back to our awaitable object because that other task completed")
        asyncio.create_task(other_task("The event loop gets control when `yield` points (from an iterable coroutine) propagate up to the `current_task` through a suitable chain of `await` or `yield from` statements"))

async def coro():
    task_print("  'Jumped straight into' coro; the `await` keyword itself does nothing to 'pause' the current_task")
    await AwaitableCls()
    task_print("  'Jumped straight back into' coro; we have another pending task, but leaving an `__await__` doesn't 'pause' the task any more than entering the `__await__` does")

@types.coroutine
def iterable_coro(context):
    task_print(f"`{context} iterable_coro`: pre-yield")
    yield None # None or a Future object are the only legitimate yields to the task in asyncio
    task_print(f"`{context} iterable_coro`: post-yield")

async def original_task():
    asyncio.create_task(other_task("Aha, but a (suitably unconsumed) *`yield`* DOES 'pause' the current_task allowing the event scheduler to `_wakeup` another task"))

    task_print("Original task")
    await coro()
    task_print("'Jumped straight out of' coro. Leaving a coro, as with leaving/entering any awaitable, doesn't give control to the event loop")
    res = await iterable_coro("await")
    assert res is None
    asyncio.create_task(other_task("This doesn't run until the very end because the generated None following the creation of this task is consumed by the `for` loop"))
    for y in iterable_coro("for y in"):
        task_print(f"But 'ordinary' `yield` points (those which are consumed by the `current_task` itself) behave as ordinary without relinquishing control at the async/task-level; `y={y}`")
    task_print("Done with original task")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(original_task())
```

run in python3.8 produces

> Task-1: Original task
>
> Task-1:   'Jumped straight into' coro; the `await` keyword itself does nothing to 'pause' the current_task
>
> Task-1:     'Jumped straight into' another `await`; the act of `await awaitable` *itself* doesn't 'pause' anything
>
> Task-2: Aha, but a (suitably unconsumed) *`yield`* DOES 'pause' the current_task allowing the event scheduler to `_wakeup` another task
>
> Task-1:     We're back to our awaitable object because that other task completed
>
> Task-1:   'Jumped straight back into' coro; we have another pending task, but leaving an `__await__` doesn't 'pause' the task any more than entering the `__await__` does
>
> Task-1: 'Jumped straight out of' coro. Leaving a coro, as with leaving/entering any awaitable, doesn't give control to the event loop
>
> Task-1: `await iterable_coro`: pre-yield
>
> Task-3: The event loop gets control when `yield` points (from an iterable coroutine) propagate up to the `current_task` through a suitable chain of `await` or `yield from` statements
>
> Task-1: `await iterable_coro`: post-yield
>
> Task-1: `for y in iterable_coro`: pre-yield
>
> Task-1: But 'ordinary' `yield` points (those which are consumed by the `current_task` itself) behave as ordinary without relinquishing control at the async/task-level; `y=None`
>
> Task-1: `for y in iterable_coro`: post-yield
>
> Task-1: Done with original task
>
> Task-4: This doesn't run until the very end because the generated None following the creation of this task is consumed by the `for` loop

Indeed, exercises such as the following can help one's mind to decouple the functionality of `async`/`await` from notion of "event loops" and such. The former is *conducive to* nice implementations and usages of the latter, but you can use `async` and `await` just as specially syntaxed generator stuff without *any* "loop" (whether `asyncio` or otherwise) whatsoever:

```py
import types # no asyncio, nor any other loop framework

async def f1():
    print(1)
    print(await f2(),'= await f2()')
    return 8

@types.coroutine
def f2():
    print(2)
    print((yield 3),'= yield 3')
    return 7

class F3:
   def __await__(self):
        print(4)
        print((yield 5),'= yield 5')
        print(10)
        return 11

task1 = f1()
task2 = F3().__await__()
""" You could say calls to send() represent our
   "manual task management" in this script.
"""
print(task1.send(None), '= task1.send(None)')
print(task2.send(None), '= task2.send(None)')
try:
    print(task1.send(6), 'try task1.send(6)')
except StopIteration as e:
    print(e.value, '= except task1.send(6)')
try:
    print(task2.send(9), 'try task2.send(9)')
except StopIteration as e:
    print(e.value, '= except task2.send(9)')
```

produces

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3 = task1.send(None)
>
> 4
>
> 5 = task2.send(None)
>
> 6 = yield 3
>
> 7 = await f2()
>
> 8 = except task1.send(6)
>
> 9 = yield 5
>
> 10
>
> 11 = except task2.send(9)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, await passes control back to the asyncio eventloop, and allows it to schedule other async functions.

Another way is

```
await asyncio.sleep(0)
```